# What Is The Best Way To Display Pixel Art In Sprite Kit?

Tags: sprite-kit, pixel

I'm curious to how I would display pixel art for my game. For now i'm just resizing the `SKScene` to be `sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(256, 192)` is this the correct way or is there a bester way to go about doing this sort of task?

Comment: what does the scene size have to do with pixel art? All you need is to set textures to use nearest filtering mode (default: linear) if you do not want pixels to "blur" due to filtering

Comment: @LearnCocos2D when I set the scene size it "Zooms" in to the pixel art which allows me to view the pixels as images, for example are 32*32.

Comment: that would make everything zoomed in, including UI and text. You can achieve the same effect via node.scale

Comment: @LearnCocos2D How would I scale a Node? there is not property as i can see

Comment: don't worry it's [node setScale:float];

Comment: @LearnCocos2D When I do this it affects the `xScale` of the sprite, this put's me in a position where I cannot flip the spite on the x axis now which is something major in the game. Is there any other method?

Comment: you can still flip, say if xscale is 4 then the flipped sprite would have to have an xscale of -4

Answer (score 8):

First, use the default sizes of scenes - you do not need to scale or change their sizes, this is just bad.

Next just scale your sprites either beforehand (in Photoshop for example) using nearest neighbor scale method - this keeps pixels separate and does not introduce antialias.

So for example if you have original 32x32 asset, scale it to 64x64 or 128x128 and use it in game. It will look great and all.

Another way is to have assets at original size, but scale them at runtime.

Here .xScale and .yScale properties of SKSpriteNode come in handy.

But if you scale your sprite it will lose its crispiness - antialiasing artifacts will appear all over.

You have two ways to deal with this - either create textures first and set their filtering method to nearest neighbour like so:

```
texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
```

But this gets out of hand fast, so I suggest using the category on SKTextureAtlas instead:

SKTextureAtlas+NearestFiltering.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface SKTextureAtlas (NearestFiltering)

- (SKTexture *)nearestTextureNamed:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

SKTextureAtlas+NearestFiltering.m

```
#import "SKTextureAtlas+NearestFiltering.h"

@implementation SKTextureAtlas (NearestFiltering)

- (SKTexture *)nearestTextureNamed:(NSString *)name
{
    SKTexture *temp = [self textureNamed:name];
    temp.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    return temp;
}

@end
```

This way you can create SKSpriteNodes by calling this method:

```
SKSpriteNode *temp = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:[self.atlas nearestTextureNamed:@"myTexture"]];
```