# How to losslessley scale UIImages in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, scaling

I am new to Swift, and am currently making a game with xcode, and have hundreds of frames of art for the game, all of which are around 60 by 60 pixes as they are pixel art. My problem arises when I try to scale the image with the generic .scale() module. As soon as I start to scale the image it immediately loses almost all of its quality and becomes incredibly fuzzy. I was wondering how I may try to scale an image so that all of its quality remains, thanks in advance! A sample of my scaling is shown below:

```
        TestSprite2.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        TestSprite2.zPosition = 1
        TestSprite2.position = CGPoint(x: TestSprite.size.width / 2, y: TestSprite.size.height / 2)
        TestSprite.addChild(TestSprite2)
```

---

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/59692616/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post about almost the same problem

[What Is The Best Way To Display Pixel Art In Sprite Kit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253518/what-is-the-best-way-to-display-pixel-art-in-sprite-kit)

by the way, there are actual algorithms to properly scale pixel art, you can read about them here

[pixel art scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel-art_scaling_algorithms#:%7E:text=Pixel%2Dart%20scaling%20algorithms%20are,drawn%202D%20pixel%20art%20graphics.&text=This%20results%20in%20graphics%20that,resolution%2C%20down%20to%20individual%20pixels.)

For starters, I suggest you to try scaling by a factor of 4 and see if that helps. so from 60 * 60, scale to 240 * 240

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion this was largely helpful

Comment: @brian.masse I am glad it helped you :) Please accept the answer or at least vote up if it helped you in any way.